# swagger file for all possible 'properties'

Tags: rest, swagger

I need to call an API to load data on an ongoing basis. API returns different properties for each event. When I create the swagger file it has properties from sample return, but in the long run there will be more properties which can be added by the source system and they will not be in swagger file.
Is there any way to recreate swagger file before data load dynamically with additional properties?

Swagger file is generated by Informatica Cloud based on a sample return while testing the connection. 
Properties list has a different number of entries based on event type.

swagger file:

```
{"swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "description" : null,
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "title" : null,
    "termsOfService" : null,
    "contact" : null,
    "license" : null
  },
  "host" : "<host>.com",
  "basePath" : "/api",
  "schemes" : [ "https" ],
  "paths" : {
    "/2.0" : {
      "post" : {
        "tags" : [ "events" ],
        "summary" : null,
        "description" : null,
        "operationId" : "events",
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "consumes" : [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "script",
          "in" : "query",
          "description" : null,
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "string"
        }, {
          "name" : "Authorization",
          "in" : "header",
          "description" : null,
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "string"
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "successful operation",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/events"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions" : {
    "events##properties" : {
      "properties" : {
        "$app_build_number" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$app_version_string" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$carrier" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$lib_version" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$manufacturer" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$model" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$os" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$os_version" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$radio" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$region" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "$screen_height" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "int32"
        },
        "$screen_width" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "int32"
        },
        "Home Step Enabled" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "Number Of Lifetime Logins" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "int32"
        },
        "Sessions" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "int32"
        },
        "mp_country_code" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "mp_lib" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "events" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "distinct_id" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "labels" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "time" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "int64"
        },
        "sampling_factor" : {
          "type" : "number",
          "format" : "int32"
        },
        "dataset" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/events##properties"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sample return:

```
    "name": "Session",
    "distinct_id": "1234567890",
    "labels": [],
    "time": 1520072505000,
    "sampling_factor": 1,
    "dataset": "$event_data_set",
    "properties": {
        "$app_build_number": "900",
        "$app_version_string": "1.9",
        "$carrier": "AT&T",
        "$lib_version": "2.0.1",
        "$manufacturer": "Apple",
        "$model": "iPhone10,6",
        "$os": "iOS",
        "$os_version": "11.2.6",
        "$radio": "LTE",
        "$region": "Florida",
        "$screen_height": 667,
        "$screen_width": 375,
        "Number Of Lifetime Logins": 2,
        "Session Length": "00h:00m:08s",
        "Sessions": 43,
        "mp_country_code": "US",
        "mp_lib": "swift"
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to insert your data in swagger? Swagger is just mean to define your request and result. E.g. This service endpoint returns List of Strings or Integers or List of Employees etc

Comment: No I won't be loading my data in swagger, "properties" part of result varies of each call, I need a superset of all available properties in swagger file

Comment: Then I can't tell much without having a look at your sample response and your properties you want to return

Comment: How do you create the Swagger file? Do you write it manually or is it generated from code? Can you post some sample responses that demonstrate the `"properties" part of result varies on each call`?

Comment: Updated the question with swagger file and sample response